# Flask page is not opening

Tags: python, flask

I have installed all Flask and other required packages on server.

When I run app.py it show this messags

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:1025/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.24.1) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
gensim Version: 3.6.0
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 267-705-778
```

But when I open this page

x.x.x.x:1025

it just keep loading. And app does not open.

This code working well on my local machine,

Code snippet of flask.app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/",  methods=['POST','GET'])
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=1025,debug = True)
```

Comment: is your route '/' returning anything?

Comment: You're going to need to show a bit more code. Making a copy of what you have, and trimming out parts until you have a small program that demonstrates the problem could be very instructive.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith: I have updated the code. Can you please check

Comment: @mmenschig: I have updated the code, can you please check it?

Comment: This error has to do with the Python version you are using, onto which `requests` is not installed correctly. I recommend [creating a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) in order to isolate the problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Thanks for the reply. But if I create virtual environment, will I able to open it on my website?

Comment: Can I install `request` and solve this? When I test it on my local machine, it is working fine, I could open it in browser. Only problem occuring no server

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: `requests` I installed, but still same issue

Comment: what is the python version you are using?

Comment: @Chathuranga: Python 3.5.2

Comment: in case you have both python 2.7 and 3.X installed in the same machine probably you have to used  ``` pip3 install ``` rather than pip install.

Comment: @Chathuranga: yes, both installed, i hbave used pip3 for installation. It incase theire is issue about package version it should not run.

Comment: since you have not created a virtualenv you might get package ambiguity. Best is to create a virtualenv and source to that and install using pip3 and run using python3.

Comment: `% virtualenv --python=python3 venv` will ensure that `venv/bin/pip` is pip3. `% venv/bin/pip install requests` will then do the right thing.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith: Thanks, I installed virtualenv and inside it I install Flask.Still problem is there.

Comment: @Chathuranga: now in venv `Python 3.5.2` and `pip 18.1 from /home/ubuntu/venv_dir/text_summary/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
`, but still no response from server

Comment: How can I confirm that port I am using is available or not?

Comment: If you dont have the port available, flask wont let you run the app.

Comment: if you are trying to access the server from outside, you should setup your reverse proxy, such as nginx (read this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)